# How to extract and calculate data by certain dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table listing name, date, order quantities. I need to compare the quantity between two dates.

I am trying to extract and calculate amount of difference by certain date range in automatically (eg: from Day-2 to Day-1).

For example in this following dataset:

- Supposed Today is 3/10/2022 so Day-1 is 2/10/2022 and Day-2 is 1/10/2022
- In D-1, Product A has 15 orders, D-2 has 10 order => difference between two dates is 5.

This formula "=INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(2022,10,3),$B$2:$F$2,0)-2)-INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(2022,10,3),$B$2:$F$2,0)-1) " works well with case above.

However, I also want to use this for calculate in bigger time range (for example a week and a month. I change this code to =INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(2022,10,3),$B$2:$F$2,0)-8)-INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(2022,10,3),$B$2:$F$2,0)-1) => the output shows: Function INDEX parameter 3 value -3 is out of range. Anyone have any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew2WE.png)

Comment: ummm Excel does not have a `Query` function.  Are you sure you do not want a Google sheets answer?  They are different.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you want to handle the output information. You can subtract the information of two columns representing two different dates. Please provide how you want the output based on the input information and also try to put the data using table markdown format so we can copy and paste for testing purpose. Check the help.

Comment: `=INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(2022,10,3),$B$2:$F$2,0)-2)-INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(2022,10,3),$B$2:$F$2,0)-1)`

Comment: I want a Google sheets answer, so if you have any recommendation, please tell me. Currently I calculate manually by subtracting the previous column from the following column, so if I need to track in different timelines, it will take a lot of time.

Comment: Please, next time use the correct tags.  I have changed it to attract those that follow the google sheets tags.

Comment: thanks all of you. This code provide my expected output. But I want the output can run automatically, so I change it to =INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(Today()),$B$2:$F$2,0)-2)-INDEX($B3:$F3,MATCH(DATE(Today()),$B$2:$F$2,0)-1) => the output provides error. how should i fix it?

Comment: `DATE(Today())` should just be `TODAY()`

Comment: Do you want the input to be a variable or set value? Also do you have an example sheet you can link?

Answer (score 0):

try in G3:

```
=INDEX(C3:C5-B3:B5)
```